# How to conditionally select a component without using *ngIf

Tags: angular

I loop through messages inside a component and would like to choose an appropriate component without using `*ngIf`. For the moment the code looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages">
    <app-message-1 *ngIf="message.type === 1" [message]="message"></app-message-1>
    <app-message-2 *ngIf="message.type === 2" [message]="message"></app-message-2>
</div>
```

and I was thinking of somethinm that looks like more of an hashmap event though it's not possible in this way (pseudo-code):

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages">
    getComponent(message.type, message);
</div>
```

ts:

```
componentsHash = {
  1:Message1Component,
  2:Message2Component
}

getComponent( type:number, message:message ) {

  return ( new componentsHash[ type ]( message ) )

}
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what is your use case in this instance but something I have used in the past is to have only one `<app-message [message]="message"></app-message>` component as you are passing same data structure to the component and then handle various condition within the component itself based on *ngIf="message.type === 1". Does this help you at all?

Comment: @CodeWarrior Sorry not at all.This is basically what my host component is doing and I'm trying to avoid the conditionning in the children components.So your solution absolutely changes nothing. But any way many thanks for your answer.

Comment: you could use a directive to accomplish something very similar to this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a directive to accomplish something very similar to this: https://fireflysemantics.medium.com/creating-a-dynamic-component-with-a-directive-7211bfe22921.

If you don't want to go down that route, then I'd recommend creating a display-based component that uses an *ngSwitch on the type. The component could be a pretty 'dumb' component, and its whole function would be to display the data that is passed down. If you go that route you could also use changedetectionStrategy.onpush to make it more performant, depending on what your display components are expected to do

Comment: I'll have a look at that and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can create a single component only and pass the message in that component like below, No need to create multiple components.

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages">
<app-message [message]="message"></app-message>
</div>
```

Now in the app-message component template (app-message.component.html) file you can use ngIf based on the message type like below:

```
<div *ngIf="message.type == 1">
 //Your content goes here
</div>

<div *ngIf="message.type == 2">
 //Your content goes here
</div>
```

This way you can achieve what you want using a single component only.

Comment: Someone already mentionned that in the comment and basically this is slightly the same thing that I'm doing for the moment.But thanks anyway.

Comment: What do you exactly want?